# Pipe into command stored in bash variable

Tags: bash, grep, pipe, variables

I enter two command in bash:

1. `$export g='grep "something"'`
2. `$echo "something and another thing" | $g`

But it doesn't work.

I want the second command to be evaluated by bash as : `echo "something and another thing" | grep "something"`

What should I do for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an alias.

```
alias g='grep "something"'
echo "something and another thing" | g
```